Toolbar resize SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE
when i have my activity with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in the AndroidManifest.xml and the keyboard go up the toolbar resize and go bigger and the (in this case) the alert dialog dont change position.

my toolbar.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="android.graphics.drawable.Drawable" />

        <variable
                name="toolbarTitle"
                type="String" />

        <variable
                name="iconDrawable"
                type="Drawable" />
    </data>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:navigationIcon="@{iconDrawable != null ? iconDrawable : @drawable/ic_arrow_back}"
            app:navigationIconTint="@color/white"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light"
            app:title="@{toolbarTitle}"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitleText"
            tools:title="Activity/Fragment name" />

</layout>

i dont have more ideas to try to fix the problem
